# navigateToUrl

Tags: apache-flex, twitter, robotlegs, navigatetourl

I'm warming up w/ AS3 robotlegs framework. I'm working on a FLEX 4/AIR Application which uses Twitter OAUTH API, my question is : where should I put my "navigateUrl" instruction so the use can authorize my token?
Is it in an Actor or in my view?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like something that would go in a Service (Actor).

For better Robotlegs support it might be more appropriate to post questions to:

http://knowledge.robotlegs.org

There's a fairly active community over there, and it helps to build the Knowledgebase.